# What sort algorithm does the dart's list library use?

Tags: algorithm, dart

Does the sort function use the Quick Sort algorithm?

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.List#id_sort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source code for `Sort` is [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/da0363172adaa266ef2d44cf87e09b61a185e79d/sdk/lib/internal/sort.dart).  Sort calls a `_doSort` helper method, which looks like this:

```
static void _doSort(List a, int left, int right, int compare(a, b)) {
  if ((right - left) <= _INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD) {
    _insertionSort(a, left, right, compare);
  } else {
    _dualPivotQuicksort(a, left, right, compare);
  }
}
```